# Escape single quotes in JSON.stringify

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I know, I don't need it, but I think I actually do.

I want to have a valid JS code rendered by `handlebarsjs` *before* it is even rendered. The JS minification tools just minify valid JS files and minifying on the fly increases processing time. This is the JS handlebars code.

```
var stringsObj = JSON.parse('{{{ json stringsDataObj }}}');
```

As you see, the single quotes up-there make that line of code a *valid* JS code. The `handlebars` helper is:

```
function json(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
}
```

And what's the problem? Well, some of the items in `stringObj` happen to have single quotes

```
stringsDataObj = {
  "str1": "I'm here",
  "str2": "You're there"
}
```

and when it rendes

```
var stringsObj = JSON.parse('"str1": "I'm here", "str2": "You're there"');
```

gives an JS error

**Is there a way to escape also single quotes in JSON.stringify?**
I tried with a replacer function, but without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should get the single quote to be displayed in the browser:

```
var final_string = JSON.stringify(context).replace(/[\/\(\)\']/g, "&apos;");
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issue with the following helper

```
function json(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context).replace(/[\/\(\)\']/g, "\\$&");
}
```

I.e., the escape must be done *after* the stringification.

Answer (score -1):

What *should* actually be rendered here is:

```
var stringsObj = JSON.parse('{"str1": "I'm here", "str2": "You're there"}');
```

JSON is valid Javascript code, it's syntactically a subset of Javascript. Which means `JSON.stringify` is outputting a *valid Javascript literal.* You don't actually need to go through the complications of generating JSON and then ensuring it's a valid *Javascript string literal* which you then parse with `JSON.parse`. You just do:

```
var stringsObj = {{{ json stringsDataObj }}};
```

Which renders:

```
var stringsObj = {"str1": "I'm here", "str2": "You're there"};
```

Which is a valid Javascript object literal.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. As I said that doesn't solve my problem cause your line before the rendering is not a valid JS code syntax.