# Setting VAL of hidden field with apostrophe for use in Django using JSON.Stringify()

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to set the value of a hidden field that I'll later grab in a Django POST, but if text has apostrophes it renders incorrectly.

**JS Array:**

```
        let vals = {
          "apple": "green",
          "banana": "yellow",
          "cherry": "Cherry's Are Red"
        }
```

**Hidden Field:**

```
<input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="testing-stringify" value="">
```

**Javascript/Jquery Stringify:**

```
$('#hidden-input').val(JSON.stringify(vals))
```

**Result in HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="testing-stringify" value="{"apple":"green","banana":"yellow","cherry":"Cherry's" are red"}>
```

As you can see, it does not render properly. Without the apostrophe, it works as expected.

**What I'm Expecting:**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="testing-stringify" value="{"apple":"green","banana":"yellow","cherry":"Cherry's are red"}">
```

What's the proper way to handle the apostrophe?

EDIT: I've also noticed it seems to choke if there are any spaces, so "Hello World" would also break it when set to the Hidden field.

Comment: `.val()` doesn't create HTML, it modifies the property in the DOM. You don't have to worry about how it's coded, it does the right thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378985/escape-single-quotes-in-json-stringify

Comment: Thanks @oalexandru - saw that article and it didn't fix my issue